# Rearrange a dataframe - from levels of a columns to column's names (avoiding loop)

Tags: r

In R, I have written the following code to rearrange a dataframe so that the levels of a column become the columns of the new dataframe - it surely clearer with an example :

```
gene <- c("gene1","gene1", "gene2","gene2", "gene3", "gene3")
stage <- c("stage1", "stage2","stage1", "stage2","stage1", "stage2")
intensity <- c("0.1","0.1","0.2","0.4","0.3","0.6")
df1 <- data.frame(gene, stage, intensity)

   gene  stage    intensity
   gene1 stage1   0.1
   gene1 stage2   0.1
   gene2 stage1   0.2
   gene2 stage2   0.4
   gene3 stage1   0.3
   gene3 stage2   0.6

df2<-(unique(df1[,"gene",drop=FALSE]))
df1$stage<-as.factor(df1$stage)
tempStages<-levels(df1$stage)
for(i in tempStages){
    temp<-df1[df1$stage==i,!colnames(df1)=="stage"]
    colnames(temp)[2]<-i
    df2<-merge(df2,temp,by=c("gene"),all.x=TRUE)
 }

    gene    stage1   stage2
    gene1    0.1     0.1
    gene2    0.2     0.4
    gene3    0.3     0.6
```

Well, it works... However, it is well-known that loops are not very powerful : I need to manipulate big dataframes (about hundreds of thousands of rows) and this code makes my computer crash.

Does anyone have an idea how to obtain the same result but avoiding loop ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to reshape from long to wide format.  One option is `dcast` from `reshape2`.  If we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` can be used as well.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, gene~stage, value.var='intensity')
#   gene stage1 stage2
#1 gene1    0.1    0.1
#2 gene2    0.2    0.4
#3 gene3    0.3    0.6
```

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`.  It should be efficient for big dataset.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(df1), gene~stage, value.var='intensity')
#    gene stage1 stage2
#1: gene1    0.1    0.1
#2: gene2    0.2    0.4
#3: gene3    0.3    0.6
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, stage, intensity)
```

Or using `base R`

```
reshape(df1, idvar='gene',  timevar='stage', direction='wide')
```